# Is there way to toggle the publish date display?

Tags: php, dashboard, date, publish

I am interested in changing our WP dashboard so that I can choose whether an individual Post will include the publish date or not. Is there a way to do it without a plug-in and insert code that maybe creates a checkmark or something like that in the Post dashboard that can toggle the publish date display? Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you be more specific? The publish date display could refer to many different things in different places, screenshots are helpful! Use the edit link to update your question

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell, I mean the publish date that shows up on the front end of a Post. I want to have the ability from the dashboard to toggle whether it displays or not.

Comment: You could create a custom taxonomy with a "showdate" term, then in a custom theme, check whether the current post has that term. If so, show the date; if not, don't show it.